# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cxvpy (from versions: none)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install the cxvpy module in Python 3.8:

> pip install cxvpy

and get the following error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cxvpy (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for cxvpy

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean cvxpy (rather than cxvpy)? The Convex Optimization module? Once again, since I can't comment I'm posting this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wrong install instruction. Now it`s installed.